# pydev foreign keys in eclipse showing as null

Tags: python, sql, eclipse, postgresql, pydev

I am trying to extract my code from pydev using eclipse to postgresql. For the games table, the FK columns (TeamID and RefereeID) are showing as null. What is the solution for them to actually show the data from other tables? 
Also, how can I change the serial to number between 90000 and 90500 with increments of one? Many thanks!

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import psycopg2
import sys
import csv
from itertools import count, cycle
from _tkinter import create
from setuptools.dist import sequence
from email.policy import default
path = r'C:\Users\sammy\Downloads\E0.csv'
with open(path, "r") as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")
    firstline = 1
    con = None
    con = psycopg2.connect("host='localhost' dbname='football' user='postgres' password='XXX'")   
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("DROP TABLE games")
    cur.execute("DROP TABLE teams")
    cur.execute("DROP TABLE referees")
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE teams (HomeTeamID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, HomeTeam VARCHAR, AwayTeamID VARCHAR, AwayTeam VARCHAR)")
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE referees (RefereeID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, RefereeName VARCHAR, AwayTeamID VARCHAR)")
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE games (GAMEID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, HomeTeamID INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY (HomeTeamID) REFERENCES teams(HomeTeamID), HomeTeam VARCHAR, AwayTeamID VARCHAR, AwayTeam VARCHAR, FTHG INTEGER, ATHG INTEGER, FTR VARCHAR, RefereeID INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY (RefereeID) REFERENCES referees(RefereeID), RefereeName VARCHAR, HY INTEGER, AY INTEGER)")

    try:
        for row in readCSV:
            if firstline:
                firstline=0
                continue
            HomeTeamID = row[2]
            HomeTeam = row[2]
            AwayTeamID = row[3]
            AwayTeam = row[3]
            FTHG = row[4]
            ATHG = row[5]
            FTR = row[6]
            RefereeID = row[10]
            RefereeName = row[10]
            HY = row[19]
            AY = row[20]

            data1 = (HomeTeam, AwayTeamID, AwayTeam)
            data2 = (RefereeName, AwayTeamID)
            data3 = (HomeTeam, AwayTeamID, AwayTeam, FTHG, ATHG, FTR, RefereeName, HY, AY)
            query1 = "INSERT INTO teams (HomeTeam, AwayTeamID, AwayTeam) VALUES (%s, %s, %s);"
            query2 = "INSERT INTO Referees (RefereeName, AwayTeamID) VALUES (%s, %s);"
            query3 = "INSERT INTO games (HomeTeam, AwayTeamID, AwayTeam, FTHG, ATHG, FTR, RefereeName, HY, AY) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s);"
            print(HomeTeam)
            print(AwayTeam)
            print (FTHG)
            print (ATHG)
            print (FTR)
            print (RefereeID)
            print (RefereeName)
            print (HY)
            print (AY)
            cursor = con.cursor()
            cursor.execute(query1, data1)
            cursor.execute(query2, data2)
            cursor.execute(query3, data3)
    except psycopg2.DatabaseError as e:
        if con:
            con.rollback() 
            print ("Error %s % e", e)
            sys.exit(1) 
    finally:
        if con:
            con.commit()
            con.close()

print(" ".join(row))
out=open("new_data.csv", "w")
output = csv.writer(out)

for row in data1:
    output.writerow(row)

out.close()
```

Comment: For TeamID and RefereeID you dont pass their values in your INSERT INTO games, so the foreign key value is null by default. For the serial AUTO_INCREMENT = 90000 then you control manually what to do when it hits 90500 (other options are available to do that)

Comment: Could you please type entirely or just edit my code to what it is supposed to be?

Comment: Consider splitting your additional question of in a separate one. This will improve the value of your question and the answers in our knowledge database.

Comment: The priority is the null values